# How to test against enum values in JSTL EL test?

Tags: jsp, enums, jstl, el

I have the following block in my JSP, which converts from ENUM values `{CREATE, CREATE_FROM_CAMPAIGN, OPEN}` into nice, readable status texts.

For some reason the first test against `'CREATE'` works, but the test against the `'CREATE_FROM_CAMPAIGN'` does not.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${entry.activity eq 'CREATE'}">
        <td>was created</td>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="$(entry.activity eq 'CREATE_FROM_CAMPAIGN'}">
        <td>was created from campaign</td>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <td>was opened (${entry.activity}) </td>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

One output from this one is as follows:

> was opened (CREATE_FROM_CAMPAIGN)
>
> was opened (OPEN)

Why does the second test not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not work because you used `$(` instead of `${` to start the expression.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${entry.activity eq 'CREATE'}">
        <td>was created</td>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${entry.activity eq 'CREATE_FROM_CAMPAIGN'}">
        <td>was created from campaign</td>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <td>was opened (${entry.activity}) </td>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just could not spot that curly bracket despite looking over that code for a long while. I've flagged my post for attention, though, because it does not benefit anyone else.